# Editing and Syncing OS X Lion Address Book with Google Contacts

Tags: macos, gmail, osx-lion, address-book, google-contacts

How do you edit contacts in the Mac OS X Lion Address Book?

There is no "edit" button when I open a contact. When I click on the number it only gives me sharing/displaying options.

Also it seems that since Lion, the sync between Google Contacts and Address Book is broken. It keeps on changing everything to the way Address Book's got it. Even when I change it on my iPhone, it synchronizes with the Gmail interface, then if I manually sync Address Book, it applies the old changes that were in the Address Book.